# load text data in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, signal-processing

I have some text files (1.txt, 2.txt,..., 60.txt) and all of them have 5 lines of header. I use the following codes, but it cannot recognize the headers and import all of the data. How I can say the matlab to start importing from a specific line?

```
num_txt=60;
input_dir='C:\data';

filenames=dir(fullfile(input_dir,'*.txt'));
i=1;
for n=1:num_txt    
    filename=fullfile(input_dir, filenames(n).name);
    img=importdata(filename);     
    data(:,i)=img(:);
    i=i+1;
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IMPORTDATA](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) has 2 additional parameters: delimiterIn and headerlinesIn.

So you use (assuming tab as a delimiter):

```
img=importdata(filename,'\t',5);
```

I'd also recommend to preallocate the `data` matrix.

Notice that for your code to work make sure all input files have the same size. Otherwise you will get error in `data(:,n)=img(:);` (yes, use `n` instead of `i`).

For above two issues you can insert into the loop:

```
if n==1
    data = zeros(numel(img),num_txt);
else
    assert(numel(img)==size(data,1),'sprintf('File %s has different size', filenames(n).name))
end
```

Comment: tnx, but how I can store all of my data in data(:,i)=img(:);?? Because it makes a separate file for each importing! I want that all of them imported data be in a single matrix.

Comment: Saw your comment after my editing. `img(:)` stretches all the data in a single file into one column vector. So your `data` matrix suppose to contain all the files.

Comment: Actually you need to use index `n`, not `i`. `data(:,n) = img(:)`. And you don't need `i=i+1;` statement. You can also store all the data into 3D array: `data(:,:,n) = img;`. Preallocate accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using readtext.m found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10946), if you know the basics and you don't want to spend much time on how to read text using MATLAB. But if you are learning, I suggest you do it yourself.